# Beginner Classes - Calling a variable name in a function and if I used a try/except properly

Tags: python, class, try-except

I just started learning Python/coding in general. I tried to find an answer to this but couldn't. So I created this code for a Class "Vehicle" in my lab:

```
class Vehicle(object):
    def __init__(self, maxspeed, mileage, color="white"):
        self.maxspeed=maxspeed;
        self.mileage=mileage;
        self.color=color;
        
    def assign_seating_capacity(self, seating_capacity):
        self.seating_capacity=seating_capacity
        
    def properties(self):
        print("Properties of the vehicle:")
        print("Maximum Speed:", self.maxspeed)
        print("Mileage:", self.mileage)
        print("Color:", self.color)
        try:
            print("Seating Capacity:", self.seating_capacity) 
        except AttributeError:
            print("Seating capacity unknown")
```

And then I created a few objects, "vehicle1", vehicle2" and so forth. My first question: is there a way to call a variable name in the function "properties"? So instead of saying "Properties of the vehicle:" it would say "Properties of vehicle1:"? Or is that way too complicated?

My second question is did I use the try/except properly? I thought I was so clever with how I got around the error that happened if I used the "properties" method without first using the "assign_seat_capacity" one. But in my lab they just did it like this:

```
class Vehicle:
    color = "white"

    def __init__(self, max_speed, mileage):
        self.max_speed = max_speed
        self.mileage = mileage
        self.seating_capacity = None
```

Is it smarter to do it this way or does it not really matter?
Thank you in advance for reading all of this! <3

I had no idea what to do but I tried
print("Properties of", self, ":")
and name, self.name, variable - even though I knew they wouldn't work

Comment: to be able to differentiate one vehicle from another you are going to need to implement an id. This may be easier to do if you generate your vehicles in a loop. Maybe something like `vehicles = [Vehicle(maxspd, mile, color, id) for id in range(NUM_VEHICLES)]`. Obviously you will have to add an actual `id` property to your Vehicle class.

Comment: In general, you shouldn't design your programs such that *variable names contain data*. Variables are for people *reading source code*. Instead, you should add an attributre, `name`, and provide a value, like `"vehicle1"` for that attribute. Don't put that information in a variable name because that isn't readily accessible (you can go through some arcane hijinks to get there, but it isn't what you should be doing)

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Thank you! Your answer helped me the most and made me realize how complicated I was making it, when like you said, I could just make name another argument/attribute. I think part of the problem is they're teaching us to name our variables things like vehicle1 or redcircle.

Comment: @OneMadGypsy Thank you! I honestly tried to implement this but I couldn't get it to work. However, your comment led me to many more helpful posts by giving me the vocabulary to search stuff like "how to create class objects with a loop". I think its just over my head at this point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you maintain your Vehicle instances in a list then you effectively get what you want. Rather than having a distinct variable for each Vehicle instance it's just an offset into a list.

For example:

```
class Vehicle:
    _id = -1
    def __init__(self, maxspeed: int, mileage: int, colour: str='white', seating_capacity: int|None=None):
        self.maxspeed = maxspeed
        self.mileage = mileage
        self.colour = colour
        self._seating_capacity = seating_capacity
        Vehicle._id += 1
        self._id = Vehicle._id
    @property
    def seating_capacity(self) -> str|int:
        return 'Unknown' if self._seating_capacity is None else self._seating_capacity
    @seating_capacity.setter
    def seating_capacity(self, value: int):
        self._seating_capacity = value
    def __str__(self):
        return f'ID: {self._id}\nMax speed: {self.maxspeed}\nMileage: {self.mileage:,}\nColour: {self.colour}\nSeating capacity: {self.seating_capacity}\n'

vehicles: list[Vehicle] = []

vehicles.append(Vehicle(150, 1))
vehicles.append(Vehicle(120, 15000, 'blue', 4))

print(*vehicles, sep='\n')

vehicles[0].seating_capacity = 5
vehicles[1].maxspeed = 145

print('---Data changed---')
print(*vehicles, sep='\n')
```

**Output:**

```
ID: 0
Max speed: 150
Mileage: 1
Colour: white
Seating capacity: Unknown

ID: 1
Max speed: 120
Mileage: 15,000
Colour: blue
Seating capacity: 4

---Data changed---
ID: 0
Max speed: 150
Mileage: 1
Colour: white
Seating capacity: 5

ID: 1
Max speed: 145
Mileage: 15,000
Colour: blue
Seating capacity: 4
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This is perfect. I understand what you were saying in another comment about 0 being way different to none but I had no idea I could set it to None in the arguments that way. I’ve also had such a hard time figuring out how to create lists or dictionaries in this type of situation so that’s extremely helpful(!!!), thank you. The Class methods I’m going to need to figure out fully, though. I get what’s happening, but I couldn’t write that myself yet.  But now I know to research decorators and __str__ functions.

Comment: Even though you did effectively solve the problem, if I did still want an identifier being printed, is the best way to just add a name argument to this code? Maybe in a similar way to how you did seating capacity, with a default set to None? The names could coincide with the list index. Or maybe a dictionary where the keys are the identifier and the values are the data? I don’t even know if that’s possible. Sorry if this is beyond, you already took the time to answer my original question 

Comment: @LaurenKai Code edited. This technique may not be thread-safe. You will also get incorrect values for ID if you remove instances from the target list. However, if you only ever build a list of Vehicle instances in a single thread then the instance ID will correspond to index in the list

Comment: thank you so so much! I really appreciate it and learning so much from this!

Answer (score 1):

```
class Vehicle(object):
    def __init__(self, maxspeed, mileage, color="white", seating_capacity=0):
        self.maxspeed = maxspeed
        self.mileage = mileage
        self.color = color
        self.seating_capacity = seating_capacity

    def assign_seating_capacity(self, seating_capacity):
        self.seating_capacity = seating_capacity

    def properties(self):
        print("Properties of the vehicle:")
        print("Maximum Speed:", self.maxspeed)
        print("Mileage:", self.mileage)
        print("Color:", self.color)
        print("Seating Capacity:", self.seating_capacity)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"""
        Properties of the vehicle:
        Maximum Speed {self.maxspeed}
        Mileage: {self.mileage}
        Color: {self.color}
        Seating Capacity: {self.seating_capacity}
        """


if __name__ == "__main__":
    C = Vehicle(100, 24)
    C.assign_seating_capacity(20)
    C.properties()
    print(C)
    D = Vehicle(55, 15, "black", 4)
    print(D)
```

If you assign seating_capacity in the object init you won't need the try/except in the properties function.
I added a **repr** function, which is what is called if you call print on an object.

Comment: this doesn't really answer the question.

Comment: Thank you! Making seating capacity a keyword argument set to 0 like that is way more intuitive than what the lab was doing! I used your way instead. I was also able to delete the assign seat capacity method because of that change. Unfortunately your repr function is over my head but I will definitely be researching them!

Comment: There is a significant difference between the seating_capacity being zero and it being non-existent. A better default would be None which you can explicitly test

Comment: Note that this is REALLY not how you should write your `__repr__` method. `__repr__` is expected by other Python programmers to produce something that _looks_ like a Python object. Usually custom reprs are reproducing the line of code used to construct the object (so `return f"""Vehicle({self.maxspeed}, {self.mileage}, color="{self.color}", seating_capacity={self.seating_capacity})"""`

Comment: Consider instead using a `__str__` method.

Answer (score 0):

Updated suggestion:

```
class Vehicle(object):
    def __init__(self, maxspeed, mileage, brand, color="white"):
        self.maxspeed=maxspeed
        self.mileage=mileage
        self.color=color
        self.brand=brand     
        
    def assign_seating_capacity(self, seating_capacity):
        self.seating_capacity=seating_capacity
        
    def properties(self):
        print(f"\nProperties of the {self.brand} vehicle:")
        print("Maximum Speed:", self.maxspeed)
        print("Mileage:", self.mileage)
        print("Color:", self.color)
        
        try:
            print("Seating Capacity:", self.seating_capacity)
        except:
            print("Seating Capacity unknown")
            

if __name__ == '__main__':
    
    gm = Vehicle(100, 80000, 'GM','red')
    gm.assign_seating_capacity(8)
    ford = Vehicle(125, 100000,'FORD')
    
    gm.properties()
    ford.properties()
    
    print('\nUpdate:')
    ford.mileage=75000
    ford.seating_capacity=5
    ford.properties()
    
    del(ford.seating_capacity)
    ford.properties()
```

Output:

```
Properties of the GM vehicle:
Maximum Speed: 100
Mileage: 80000
Color: red
Seating Capacity: 8

Properties of the FORD vehicle:
Maximum Speed: 125
Mileage: 100000
Color: white
Seating Capacity unknown

Update:

Properties of the FORD vehicle:
Maximum Speed: 125
Mileage: 75000
Color: white
Seating Capacity: 5

Properties of the FORD vehicle:
Maximum Speed: 125
Mileage: 75000
Color: white
Seating Capacity unknown
```

Comment: Thank you! You fixed both issues by making them both arguments/attributes, combining what two people said (with brand instead of name). And bonus - you gave me a new way to call attributes with the curly brackets.

Comment: `self.seat` will never be defined, so the `hasattr` will always throw an error and get caught by the except block.

Comment: Did you notice the NameError exception in your faulty code? Why would you use strings for maxspeed, mileage and seat? They're clearly meant to be numeric

Comment: @LaurenKai, and others. Thanks for your comments, I have corrected my answer.